# Ant: How to call a directory with php files and save the result as overwritten files

Tags: ant

How can I use Ant to execute **each** php file in a directory? The output for the php execution should overwrite the original file.

The directory is on a localhost webserver with php installed. I assume the solution would involve GET and have src point to the http equivalent of each file.

Some dynamic version of
c:/webroot/php/file1.php
c:/webroot/php/file2.php

translate into
get src="localhost/php/file1.php"
get src="localhost/php/file2.php"

and then have the output overwrite itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the [php command line](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php) combined with the ANT [apply](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) task?

Something like:

```
<apply executable="C:\PHP5\php.exe">
    <arg value="-f"/>
    <fileset dir="c:/webroot/php" includes="*.php"/>
</apply>
```

It's not clear to me why you want to overwrite your source files....

## Update

Alternatively use an embedded [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) script

```
<fileset id="phpfiles" dir="c:/webroot/php" includes="*.php"/>

<groovy>
   project.references.phpfiles.each {
      def file = new File(it.toString())
      ant.get(src:"http://localhost/php/${file.name}", dest:"output/${file.name}")
   }
</groovy>
```

Comment: For another user this might be a good way. I am looking for a way to do it through the XAMPP web server, over Get.